# Sass import from rails engine not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've created a Rails Engine for assets. I don't use sprockets for css. Instead, I rely on sass's @import. This works perfectly fine in the test/dummy app, but in the Rails app that is requiring the engine, it keeps throwing

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: gumby.
```

I've been at this for a while, and originally the path wasn't in the load path for sass. But then I added

```
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['gumby_on_rails'].full_gem_path}/app/assets/stylesheets"
```

to my `config/application.rb` and now it definitely shows the correct path to the file I'm trying to import. It is the second to the last path listed in the following trace:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: gumby.
Load paths:
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  CompassRails::SpriteImporter
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/app/assets/images
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@blog/gems/angularjs-rails-1.0.7/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@blog/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@blog/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.11@blog/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/gumby/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/brandon/code/personal/blog_update/app/assets/stylesheets
```

The rails engine's tree looks like this

```
app/
  assets/
    stylesheets/
      gumby/
        ...
      gumby.css.scss
```

(I know that technically you should namespace all your assets in an engine, but I didn't want to have gumby/gumby, and I feel the chances of a name clash are slim.)

So in the test/dummy app I can import this file via `@import 'gumby';`, but this fails in the Rails app. With the above exception. How do I get this working?

And by the way, this is a Rails 4.1 app, and the answers to several other "similar" questions are all due to using groups in the Gemfile. Rails 4 got rid of groups so this is not the problem/solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution for me was to suck it up and namespace it `gumby/gumby`. Then I also had to change the `config/application.rb` to:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['gumby_on_rails'].full_gem_path}/app/assets/stylesheets"
```

And for some reason `modular-scale` wasn't being required properly, even though the engine already required it. So I had to change `application.css.scss` to `application.css.scss.erb` and put `<% require 'modular-scale' %>` at the top.

Comment: Finally! With Rails 4.2.1, I've had a heck of a time figuring out how to add a Sass load_path. `config.sass.load_paths`, `Sass::Engine::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:load_paths]`, and `Sass::Plugin.options[load_paths]` seem to have no effect (unlike in the original question, I did not see the path listed in the trace), but `config.assets.paths` works..

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe my problem was that I needed to add a non-Sass path--I see that my error was from `ActionView::Template::Error`, not `Sass::SyntaxError`. Nonetheless, this answer seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

then you should write it like this :

```
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['gumby_on_rails'].full_gem_path}/app/assets/stylesheets/gumby"
```

or try this (untested)

```
@import_tree 'gumby';
```

Comment: This looks like it could possibly have solved my issue, if I hadn't already solved it another way.